# How do i make a Dialog box show up when a person has failed to put the correct password?

Tags: java

Okay this is my code that I need to work, the rest I think is probably irrelevant.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int failT = 1;
    String answer = pass.getText(); 
    if (answer.equals(password)){
        System.out.println("CORRECT!!");

        pass.setText("");
    }
    else {
        failT =+ 1;
        pass.setText("");
        if (failT >= 3){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SORRY, you have failed 3 times goodbye");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace

```
failT =+ 1;
```

with

```
failT += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`failT` is a local variable to the `actionPerormed` method, which is initialised to `1` each time the method is called, this means that it is impossible for the value to ever be `>= 3`

You need to define topics value as a class/instance field, so it's value is maintained at the class level instead

Take a look at [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details.

Comment: Actually, `failT =+ 1` will compile clean. Although it won't do what OP wants it to do.

Comment: Indeed, what @wil93 says is true. `failT =+ 1` is translated by the compiler as `failT = +1` and compiles but does not behave as the OP thinks. 1+ to both your answers.

Comment: Okay, but it freaks me out

Comment: ... or should that be +1 to both of your answers?